# Array to string conversion into a foreach

Tags: php

I don't understand why I have this error while var_dump returns me good value for " $valReponse."

I use a foreach because " $reponses" is an array of strings. I try to insert data into a table and I get the error "Array conversion to sting." Where did I wrong?

The PHP :

```
foreach ($reponses as $reponse => $valReponse) {

  var_dump($valReponse);

  if ($insert_reponses = $this->getConnexion()->prepare('INSERT INTO SD_reponses (reponse_val, question_id) VALUES (?, ?)') or die(mysqli_error($this->getConnexion()))) {

    $insert_reponses->bind_param("si", $valReponse, $question_id);
    $insert_reponses->execute();
    $insert_reponses-> close();

  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

return true;
```

The var_dump result:

```
array (size=1)  0 => string 'Answer 1 ' (length=9)<br>
array (size=1)  0 => string 'Answer 2 ' (length=9)
```

It works, however, in `reponse_val` column (in the database), the value "Array" is inserted instead of the value I expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$valResponse` variable is an array with one element, not a string. You need to do this instead:

```
$insert_reponses->bind_param("si", $valReponse[0], $question_id);
```

Comment: By an unfortunate manipulation, I permanently deleted my class this morning and files that it was appealing. So I had to rewrite my PHP files, and now if I put " $valReponse[0] " xdebug said to me, "only variables should be passed by reference". Whereas if I leave " $valReponse ", it works. An explanation?

Answer (score 1):

When you are not sure of the index(/association) of the first array-item, use:

```
  $insert_reponses->bind_param("si", current(array_values($valReponse)), $question_id);
```

or

```
  $insert_reponses->bind_param("si", array_shift($valReponse), $question_id);
```